# What are drawbacks of storing text data in one large ASCII text file as compared to splitting it up to multiple files?

Tags: split, text-files, storage

What are three main drawbacks of storing text data in one large ASCII text file as compared to splitting it up to multiple files?  If I do split up, could you suggest a heuristic to choose a threshold size?

Comment: This sounds a bit like a homework question...?

Comment: What is the purpose of the data storage?

Comment: It's not a homework question.

Comment: For archiving data so it needs not to be recomputed when it needs to be reused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically loading the file into an editor is the big problem so if the use case for the file involves a user opening it up then its good to split it up.

For example when logging exceptions to a file I usually limit the size of the log file to 50 MB, because I know most text editors with current typical hardware can handle that pretty easily. This  will change of course change with OS and hardware improvements. So 20 years from now mutli-GB text files might load nicely.

If you transferring data on the other hand the limits should be tuned to the transport mechanism. For example many email systems cap attachments around 10 MB.

Comment: Thanks for constructive comments and partial answer.